# codeigniter NetworkError: 404 Not Found after POST action

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, post

i'm working on a codeigniter project. on one page i have a form (to login) and that one works fine. but now i have a form to update my database, but i get a NetworkError: 404 Not Found (in firebug).

this is my form

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>cms/activiteit/saveNew" method="post">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">Titel:</div>
    <input class="col-md-9" type="text" name="title"/>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">Datum:</div>
    <input class="col-md-9" type="date" name="date" id="date"/>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">Korte beschrijving:</div>
    <input class="col-md-9" type="text" name="short"/>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">Lange beschrijving:</div>
    <textarea class="col-md-9" type="text" name="long"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 spatie"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <input type="submit" class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-3 btn btn-info" value="Opslaan"/>
</div>
```

and this is my controller

```
public function saveNew()
{
    if(isset($_POST))
    {
        echo "test";

        $acti = new Activiteiten();

        $acti->title = $this->input->post('title');
        $acti->date = $this->input->post('date');
        $acti->short = $this->input->post('short');
        $acti->long = $this->input->post('long');
        $acti->save();
    }
    else 
    {
        echo 'no post'; 
    }
}
```

when i look in to the post value on firebug all the data from the input fields is there but there is no way that i can display then or do an insert in my database with it.

firebug headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Tue, 17 Jun 2014 19:27:40 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.27 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.27 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.27
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html
POST /cms/activiteit/saveNew HTTP/1.1
Host: perdje.be
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: nl,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://perdje.be/cms/activiteit/add
Cookie: cprelogin=no; cpsession=perdje1q%3aiLdNSXOGrC7JqfYiwXW5ZEgZzOV7w7Yu0Cs36PnP0Jq__JK7958XQpEYD6tHRNrB%2c01946c78c16598ea1c0c6c7ff8917d333105a9eae2e7fbc65887fd48c550de8b; langedit=; lang=
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

if anybody sees what i'm doing wrong pleas let me know. i tried changing my .htacces, the config files form codeigniter, different ways of showing post data, trying to show some post data. but nothing worked. please help

Comment: `<?php echo base_url('cms/activiteit/saveNew'); ?>`

Comment: how about `echo site_url('cms/activiteit/saveNew');` ?

Comment: the problem is not situated in the form (i think), because in the saveNew() function the echo gets displayed. thanks a lot